# NSManagedObject has changed, but NSManagedObjectContext hasn't

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using `MagicalRecord` in my app. I have an `NSManagedObject` subclass that have a property called `isFavorite` which is a `BOOL (NSNumber)`.

When I set that property, the `NSManagedObject` subclass `hasChanges` method returns `TRUE`, but if I access that `NSManagedObject`'s Context, the `hasChanges` method of it sometimes returns `FALSE`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
self.controlledDevice = [WUDevice MR_findFirstWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deviceIdInHub = %@", deviceId]];
self.controlledDevice.isFavorite = @(![self.controlledDevice.isFavorite boolValue]);
//At this point, [self.controlledDevice hasChanges] always returns true, but [self.controlledDevice.managedObjectContext hasChanges] sometimes returns false, sometimes true.
```

Does anyone have any idea of why can this happen?

**EDIT:**

The 'sometimes' behaviour is run to run. Meaning, if some NSManagedObject doesn't promote changes to the context, and i restart the application, it can start working as expected.

I think the problem is because of the NSManagedObjectContext isn't being notified about the change in one of it's NSManagedObjects, because in the same run i request the same object again, i receive it with the changes, but it doesn't save those changes to the persistent store.

Comment: Just to be clear, this has no bearing on your use of MagicalRecord. This is a CoreData behavior.

Comment: I though that, i just commented that i'm using MagicalRecord, but i also think it has to be with CoreData

Comment: Can you elaborate on "sometimes returns false, sometimes true"?  Like, if you log it in a loop, does it change, or is it run to run?  Is it correlated with the initial value of isFavorite?  It it was, that would be a good hint about the cause.